# Login to server using fingerprint

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint

I'm trying to authenticate users to the backend server using fingerprint.

The scenario that I can think of is when user registers with  a new account, I should send some sort of a unique identifier to the server related to the fingerprint..

Later the user can send only that unique id to the server to log in with no passwords or emails or any other credentials..

Is that possible?
If so, how?

Comment: One possibility: When the user registers their account you create an asymmetric keypair that requires fingerprint authentication and share the public key with the server. When the user wants to log in you send some value to the server that identifies the user's public key (e.g. a [public key fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint)). The server responds by giving you some data to sign. Then the user performs a fingerprint authentication, which allows you to use their private key to sign the data that you got from the server. And then the server verifies the signature.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible since it has been done.

As the user registers with or for a new account, you also  [enroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometrics) one or more fingerprints. To do that, a fingerprint scanner is required. (Note that the fingerprint 
 image that the Android fingerprint reader captures, cannot be "taken" out of the phone. You need an external fingerprint reader.)

Also needed is some sort of SDK for extracting a *template* from the fingerprint image. (The template is close to what you might be calling the unique identifier, although it might not really be that unique.) The manufacturer of the fingerprint reader, usually also supplies the SDK. If they do not, you'll need a third-party SDK. One can search online for those.

The extracted template is stored on the server alongside other user data. At login, you extract a template from the same finger, transmit it to the server, and search amongst the previously *enrolled* templates. For that search (identification), you also need some SDK, or some sort of AFIS. There are commercial as well as free offerings (such as [sourceAfis](https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/)).

A better explanation is given in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometrics).

Comment: so I have to use an external finger print scanner to be able to extract that template, right?

Comment: @OmarLabib You have to use an external reader to be able to _capture_ an image of the fingerprint. You can perform template extraction in software, or save the image and extract the template at a later time. (If you will be using SourceAFIS, for example, they recommend that you keep a copy of the image, for future extraction of templates. Whether or not  regulations allow that, is a different matter.)

Comment: While doing some research, I came accross this article from Android developers, it explains the idea of Asymmetric Keys..
Can this do the job?

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html

Comment: @OmarLabib That example does not do what you want, if I understand you correctly. You want to use the fingerprint to _identify_ a user, from a set of other users, just as one would use a username and password. On the other hand, unless I am gravely mistaken, the Asymmetric Keys example is about proving that one particular individual, who _alone_ is tied to that device, is using that particular device.

Comment: It is possible to use that method, provided each person uses their phone as access device; that is, if a user logs in with his/her phone, and works from the phone.

Comment: Please some more details

Comment: I am not sure anymore what your use case is.  Between the answer above, on one hand, and the  asymmetric key scenario on the other hand, you should be able to choose what you want.